# Stripped-down vs bare-bones

Tags: meaning, adjectives, nuance

I understand that "stripped-down" and "bare-bones" probably mean the same thing for most people, but are there nuances that make them different?

I tend to feel that "bare-bones" has all the essentials (or standard features) but not more, while "stripped-down" can be even less than that, possibly to the point of having the very minimal set of functions that a specific use case needs, and that doesn't even provide very basic/standard features that are not essential for its functioning (e.g. standard-compliant safety features). Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "bare-bones" means the minimal version, like you said. But to me, "stripped-down" essentially means "reduced", but it's not necessarily clear whether it's reduced to less than the bare minimum or not.